# Core dump when global variable used

Tags: c++, global-variables, coredump

```
#include <iostream>

int sizeWhileBuilding = 0;
int sizeWhileCounting = 0;

struct Node
{
   Node( int theData ) :
      data( theData ), left( NULL ), right( NULL )
   { std::cout << "Node::Node() with data " << theData << std::endl; }

   int data;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
};

Node* insertNode( Node* root, int data )
{
   if( !root )
   {
      ++sizeWhileBuilding;
      std::cout << "Current size is " << sizeWhileBuilding << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Making new node with " << data << std::endl;
      root = new Node( data );
   }
   else if( root->data < data )
   {
      std::cout << "The node " << root->data << " is lesser than " << data << ". Making right node" << std::endl;
      root->right = insertNode( root->right, data );
   }
   else if( root->data > data )
   {
      std::cout << "The node " << root->data << " is greater than " << data << ". Making left node" << std::endl;
      root->left = insertNode( root->left, data );
   }
   return root;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Making binary tree" << std::endl;

   Node* root;
   if( root )
   {
      std::cout << "Root is NOT null after creation" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Root is null after creation" << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "==============================================================================" << std::endl;
   root = insertNode( root, 10 );

//Problem line below
std::cout << "The size of the tree is " << sizeWhileBuilding << std::endl;
}
```

When I run this code with the "problem line" commented out, it runs and inserts node 10 into the tree. When I run it with the problem line, I see that it coredumps.

When I run without the problem line, I see that the else part at the beginning of main prints "Root is null after creation". With the problem`enter code here` line, "Root is NOT null after creation is printed".

What I don't understand is why the Node* root; initialization depends upon whether the global variable is being used?

Answer (score 1):

```
Node* root;
```

`root` is a local variable and if not initialized its value will be garbage. So sometimes it might be nullptr other times anything else. So if used it will cause  undefined behaviour that may end in coredump. The solution is to assign it:

```
Node* root = nullptr;
```

also:

> What I don't understand is why the Node* root; initialization depends upon whether the global variable is being used?

if you have undefined behaviour in your code then anything is possible, also such strange behaviour as you describe.